# How to convert String to int

Tags: java, string, int

I am using BufferedReader to read a line of integers and doubles from a csv file. However, I need to call individual variables and make calculations with them as ints and doubles, rather than as Strings, which I believe is the only way BufferedReader imports the variables.

This is the BufferedReader code I am using:

```
  String csvFile = "M:\\MandNDrives\\mwallace\\JAVA for NEMS\\EORModule\\NEMSEORDBEX1.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String [] reservoir = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            REG = reservoir[3];
            DEP = reservoir[4];
```

And I am getting the error: "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String" when I attempt this calculation.

```
public void varCalc(){

    switch (REG){
        case 1: TEMP = 0.107*DEP+61.065; break;
        case 2: TEMP = 0.0123*DEP+80.302; break;
```

Comment: `the only way BufferedReader imports the variables` What do you mean?

Comment: What don't you understand in `"incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String"`?

Comment: Use a [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instead?

Comment: Or use `Integer.parseInt` - and ideally fix your variable names to be less shouty.

Comment: You don't state which line of code you're getting the error. You're throwing away one line of input. The line you're getting the error on has nothing to do with BufferedReader or importing or defining it or switch statements whatsoever. -1 for poor quality question.

Answer (score 0):

Type of reserviro array is String, so you need to parse the value to int type by using:

```
Integer.parseInt
```

in order to be able to use the value in your calculation in below section of your code as an example

```
case 1: TEMP = 0.107*Integer.parseInt(DEP)+61.065; break;
```

Answer (score 0):

TEMP is of type int?
try either

- new `Double(DEP).doubleValue()` to convert `DEP` to `double` or
- `Double.valueOf(DEP).doubleValue();` or
- `Integer.parseInt(DEP)` (preferred)

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to your error:

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String

You need to use:

```
case 1: TEMP = 0.107*Integer.parseInt(DEP)+61.065; break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has wrapper classes for turning strings into primitive values. An example below, I read in a csv file full of integers, and for each integer I parse it from a string to an integer variable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File file = new File("input.txt");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String [] values = sc.nextLine().split(",");
        for(String s : values){
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

You can do the same with `Double.parseDouble`, `Long.parseLong`, etc. Then you can use that variable for calculations.

Comment: That seems to be on the track of what I need to do. However, how would I be able to read through String s to identify individual variables contained in file (which is a csv file)?

Comment: How do you mean? You could use a `for` loop, with an index value. All of the values would be in the location you specified (aligned with headers), so if you needed DEP and you knew it was the 3rd column, you could do `int i = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);`.